# Doubt in proof of Chebysheff theorem

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, chebyshev-function

While self studying analytic number theory from Introduction to sieve methods and it's applications by M Ram Murthy  and Alina Carmen,I have a doubt in theorem 1.4.1 proof by Chebysheff.

> My doubt is -> Author writes  $\frac {(2n) ! } { ( n!) ^2}  \leq  2^{2n} $  and then he writes this step which I am not able to derive - upon taking logarithms $\theta(2n)  - \theta(n) \leq  2n log 2  $

Can someone please help in how to derive this statement!!

Comment: What is $\theta$?

Comment: $\theta(x) = \sum_{p \leq x} ln( p ) $ , Its 2nd chebycheff function

Comment: I think there is a mistake. It should be $\theta(2n)-2\theta(n)$.

Comment: @broncoAbierto I checked the book again . the statement mentioned by me in question  is correct

Comment: What do you mean correct? If the book says that, I believe it is a typo. I checked numerically and my derivation below checks out.

Comment: Now that you have correctly specified the definition of $\theta$, that changes everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}=\binom{2n}{n}\in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore $p|\binom{2n}{n}$ for all primes $n<p<2n$ and $\prod_{n<p<2n}p|\binom{2n}{n}<2^{2n}$. Now use $\ln$ to get the desired inequality.

Comment: can you please look at this question if you have some time to spare. I am badly struck on it. Perhaps its not right way to ask but I really need help.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3523183/an-argument-in-paper-of-wadim-zudilin-irrationality-of-values-of-riemann-zeta-f